Upper and lower bounds for the stationary distrubution of an ergodic Markov chain
Consider an ergodic Markov chain on a finite state space $S$ ($|S|>1$) with a transition matrix $P$.
Is it possible to determine upper and lower bounds of its stationary distribution $\pi$ using only the elements of $P$ ?
Specifically, can we find constants $a_P$ and $b_p$ such that
$
0<a_P<\pi_j<b_P<1
$ for all $j\in S$ ?

If $S$ has one state then no. If $S$ is finite and has at least two states then yes, since ergodicity implies $\pi$, which depends only on $P$, is unique and has all components positive and less than $1$. So you can use $a_P=\frac{1}{2}\min_{i \in S} {\pi_i}$ and $b_P=\frac{1}{2}(1+\max_{i \in S} {\pi_i})$.

Thanks. Can we express the $a_P$ and $b_P$ using only $P$ without relying on $\pi$ ?
